# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'atomate' But I have install it

Tags: python

everyone!
I have met a problem, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'atomate'"
The error is shown below,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/bin/rlaunch", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(rlaunch())
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/scripts/rlaunch_run.py", line 141, in rlaunch
    timeout=args.timeout, local_redirect=args.local_redirect)
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/core/rocket_launcher.py", line 98, in rapidfire
    while (skip_check or launchpad.run_exists(fworker)) and time_ok():
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/core/launchpad.py", line 781, in run_exists
    return bool(self._get_a_fw_to_run(query=q, checkout=False))
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/core/launchpad.py", line 1078, in _get_a_fw_to_run
    m_fw = self.get_fw_by_id(m_fw['fw_id'])
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/core/launchpad.py", line 529, in get_fw_by_id
    return Firework.from_dict(self.get_fw_dict_by_id(fw_id))
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/utilities/fw_serializers.py", line 157, in _decorator
    new_args[0] = {k: _recursive_load(v) for k, v in args[0].items()}
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/utilities/fw_serializers.py", line 157, in <dictcomp>
    new_args[0] = {k: _recursive_load(v) for k, v in args[0].items()}
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/utilities/fw_serializers.py", line 118, in _recursive_load
    return {k: _recursive_load(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/utilities/fw_serializers.py", line 118, in <dictcomp>
    return {k: _recursive_load(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/utilities/fw_serializers.py", line 121, in _recursive_load
    return [_recursive_load(v) for v in obj]
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/utilities/fw_serializers.py", line 121, in <listcomp>
    return [_recursive_load(v) for v in obj]
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/utilities/fw_serializers.py", line 113, in _recursive_load
    return load_object(obj)
  File "/home/user/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/utilities/fw_serializers.py", line 332, in load_object
    mod = __import__(modname, globals(), locals(), [classname], 0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'atomate'
```

And another strange thing is that I import it successfully.

```
(firework) [user@master test_c]$ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 10:21:04) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import atomate
>>>
```

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from pymatgen import Structure
from fireworks import LaunchPad
from atomate.vasp.workflows.presets.core import wf_bandstructure
from atomate.vasp.powerups import add_modify_incar
struct = Structure.from_file('POSCAR')  # note: many file formats supported, see function docs
wf = wf_bandstructure(struct)
lpad = LaunchPad.auto_load() # loads this based on the FireWorks configuration
lpad.add_wf(wf)
```

So what's the problem? How can I solve it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where possible instead of posting screenshots, post any errors or other output you have as plain text.  I also encourage you to search for other `ModuleNotFoundError` questions as there are many common causes for this and it is rarely specific to any one package.

Comment: Additionally, you should not be manually adding `sys.path` entries, especially for `site-packages`.  If you're using a conda environment, make sure you have *activated* the environment by running `conda activate firework` (in your case).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even though I don't add sys.path entries, the error still appears.

Comment: From your traceback it looks like you don't have the conda environment activated when you run the code. When you run `python -c 'import fireworks; print(fireworks)` what does it output? Maybe you also need to manually install the atomate package into your environment.

Comment: The output is  `python -c "import fireworks; print(fireworks)"
<module 'fireworks' from '/home/user/app/anaconda3/envs/firework/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fireworks/__init__.py'>`